# How to create X509Certificate with keys pairs without sun.security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, x509certificate

I want to generate x509 certificate and keys pairs for my unit test.

```
private Pair<String, String> generateTokenAndCertificate() {
    try {

        //Configure generator
        CertAndKeyGen certGen = new CertAndKeyGen("RSA", "SHA256WithRSA");
        certGen.generate(2048);
        long validSecs = (long) 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; // valid for one year


        //Token
        CharSequence content = "test";
        Signer signer = new RsaSigner((RSAPrivateKey) certGen.getPrivateKey());
        String token = JwtHelper.encode(content, signer).getEncoded();

        //Certificate
        X500Name data = new X500Name("CN=Test Application,O=Company,L=City,C=DE");
        X509Certificate cert = certGen.getSelfCertificate(data, validSecs);
        Base64 encoder = new Base64();
        String certificate = X509Factory.BEGIN_CERT + "\n";
        certificate += encoder.encode(cert.getEncoded());
        certificate += X509Factory.END_CERT + "\n";

        return new Pair<>(token, certificate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have used

```
import sun.security.provider.X509Factory;
import sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen;
import sun.security.x509.X500Name;
```

And got errors like these:

> error: package sun.security.tools.keytool does not exist

and:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        CertAndKeyGen certGen = new CertAndKeyGen("RSA", "SHA256WithRSA");
        ^
symbol:   class CertAndKeyGen
location: class CertificationProviderSpecification
```

I know that `javac` doesn't load full `rt.jar` regarding `ct.sym` and I could solve such errors by `-XDignore.symbol.file` or Bouncy Castle.

But is it possible to generate these by `java.security` or `org.springframework.security`?

Answer (score 4):

You can create the key pair using only `java.security`:

```
KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
gen.initialize(2048, SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"));
KeyPair keyPair = gen.generateKeyPair();
```

But to create the certificate, you have to use `sun.security` classes.

I've never used `org.springframework.security` but one good alternative to create certificates is the [Bouncy Castle API](http://bouncycastle.org/java.html) - check at the `org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder` class, there are [lots of online examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder).